# How can enable the `Depth of Field` option in ARKit 3.0?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

In the ARKit 3.0 [demo](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/604/) by Apple, the `depth of field` effect was presented. I tried to find the documentation for this but I cannot find how we are supposed to enable this.

I found it's easy to enable the [motion blur](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/3182993-rendersmotionblur) and [noise grain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/3255193-renderscameragrain) effects. Basically there is a single flag that you set like this in Objective-C

```
scnview.rendersMotionBlur = true;
```

But nothing for the depth of field effect I could find.

Is this something not exposed to the developers yet?

Answer (score 2):

**`Depth Of Field`** is a post-processing renderer's feature of RealityKit and SceneKit frameworks. There's no `Depth Of Field` in ARKit, because ARKit isn't responsible for rendering.

### In RealityKit DoF is ON by default

**`Depth Of Field`** is one of options of a brand-new **RealityKit** companion framework. DoF of ARCamera is activated and deactivated via `ARView.RenderOptions` based on iOS device capabilities and, if your device does support it, it is `ON` by default. For turning it `OFF` you have to use a `disableDepthOfField` global type property:

```
static let disableDepthOfField: ARView.RenderOptions
```

> ***RealityKit Documentation***: Disable the depth of field effect for all virtual content.

### In SceneKit DoF is OFF by default

In a **SceneKit** framework there's a `wantsDepthOfField` instance property for virtual camera.

```
var wantsDepthOfField: Bool { get set }


let nonAR_Camera = SCNCamera()
nonAR_Camera.wantsDepthOfField = true
nonAR_Camera.focusDistance = 1.5        // distance in meters
nonAR_Camera.fStop = 4.0
```

> ***SceneKit Documentation***: A Boolean value that determines whether SceneKit renders depth-of-field blur effects for the camera

Comment: thanks for the great answer. So to confirm using Scenekit and ARSCNView there is no way to enable DepthOfField?

Comment: SceneKit gives you DoF but you can't use it in ARKit 2.0. Although I'm sure this is possible to enable DoF for ARKit 2.0 via AVFoundation framework but it's not easy.